# Search for a string in all of the files in git's staging area and all those files changed but not staged

Tags: git

I am trying to search for a string (e.g. search for string "TODO") in all of my files which are changed locally. That includes files which were already staged and those that are changed but are not added to staging area yet.

Comment: Pipe the results of a git status into grep using a for loop?

Comment: `git grep TODO`?  (Note that this starts in working directory, add `-- :/` to start at top of repository.)  This looks at unmodified files too though.

Comment: Yeah but git grep will also search files that are unchanged in the current working directory.

Comment: Readers will probably get the most benefit from answers using the commands built into git. After all, git aims directly at helping you manage 'plaintext' changes in a repo....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question. I was able to do it with the following command

```
git diff --name-only | xargs grep 'My search string goes here'
```

Comment: That doesn't find staged changes, right? For staged and unstaged changes you want `git diff HEAD`

Comment: This shows the files which are changed and search strings in that files, but what about to search only changes, added, removed strings. ?

Comment: `git diff-index --cached -S{STRINGTOSEARCH} -u HEAD` it requires at least the file added to git via `git add path/to`

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer would be

`git diff-index -S{STRINGTOSEARCH} -u HEAD`

newly added files have to be added to staging through

`git add path/to/filename`

searches the intented string in only added/removed strings.

Comment: kudos for the answer that uses the tool 'as designed' vs introducing outside, cobbled-together approaches

Answer (score 1):

I found the `-S{STRING}` version rather hard to use since regex are not straight forward. An easier version for me is to pipe the output into grep and use it's pattern matching:

```
git diff-index --cached -u HEAD | grep -i string
```

Or for multiple strings at the same time:

```
git diff-index --cached -u HEAD | grep -i -e string1 -e string2 -e string3
```

`-i` is for case insensitivity and `-e` is to add more patterns.

You can add this as an alias to your rc and check for your personal details for every commit if you want.

Comment: Being able to search multiple strings is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash snippet that works on Debian to accomplish this:

```
for file in `git status -s -uno`
        do
                if [[ ! $file =~ [A-Z] ]]; then
                        echo "$file"
                        grep -n "TODO" $file
                fi
        done
```

Explanation:

`git status -s -uno` is short form of git status but excludes untracked files.

The if condition in the for loop skips over the status part of `git status -s` to avoid searching through files that don't exist.

Finally the -n option ot grep prints the line numbers. Simply change TODO to whatever you want to find.

I imagine it ought to work on git-bash in windows too...